# WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.7 reports that it is already running when I try to start it, but it is reporting that it is stopped when I try to stop it

Tags: websphere-liberty

Virtual machine with WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.7 was restarted while serverX created on that WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.7 was still running. After machine was restarted serverX was not turned on. So it is definitely not working. There are no logs and applications are unavailable.

But I get following outputs when I try to start that server...

```
> server status serverX
Server serverX is running.

> server start serverX
Server serverX is already running.

> server stop serverX
Stopping server serverX.
Server serverX is not running.
```

Last command output means that serverX cannot be stopped, because it is not working. It does not mean that server was stopped by that command.

So how to turn it on?

Comment: I resolved it by copying server directory, removing original server directory and renaming copy to original server name, but still I'd like to know what was wrong.

Comment: After a reboot, you'd have a *.pid with a bad value in it -- but that wasn't enough for me to get the same symptom. Gotta be something in that nieghborhood though.

Comment: @covener I looked in logs directory, but there wasn't any pid file.

Comment: The pid file is in the `usr/servers/.pid/` directory by default (https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_command_server.html).  Regardless, I suspect the pid file did not already exist or else the "is already running" message would have said "with process ID ###".  What operating system is the virtual machine running?  Does the same message occur if you run start/stop repeatedly?  What file system is wlp/usr using in the virtual machine?  I would suspect some issue with file locks within the VM.

Comment: @BrettKail There is no `WLP/usr/servers/.pid` directory. Additionally there is no directory or file with `pid` in name in entire WLP directory hierarchy and there is no such file or directory in my copy of that non-working server (I have a second copy of that non-working server which is in the same state as when it was not working). But this copy works when I run it on different WebSphere Liberty. System is Windows Server 2012. 4 attempts to start and stop did not end up with the same issue. I have also killed java process, but also there was no issues with start/stop. File system is NTFS.

Comment: Windows does not use the `.pid` directory, so that makes sense.  The server status checks rely on a lock file, so my best guess is something went wrong with that file within the VM, but I'm not sure what.  If the problem happens again and causes problems, I guess I would recommend opening a PMR with IBM.

Comment: @BrettKail Ok, thanks.